# AWS Managed Airflow - How to solve 350 second timeout when triggering long running lambdas

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, network-programming, airflow

Currently when invoking lambdas using the AWS lambda hook

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/contrib/hooks/aws_lambda_hook/index.html

If the lambda runs more than 350 seconds it fails. The task itself shows its running even after 350 seconds for around an hour and then it gives the default Airflow timeout error.

My quite strong suspicion is that the issue is related to AWS NAT outgoing connection idle timeout limit that occurs for private subnets

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/nat-gateway-troubleshooting.html#nat-gateway-troubleshooting-timeout

How to solve this problem either from client side or networking side?

My ideas have been

Async lambda execution and passing certain event or triggering listener after execution is finished to continue to the next task. Naturally this is not ideal because i cant easily check the logs from Airflow side
Setup own managed Airflow in public subnet This setup is the least preferred as its unsafe and complicated

Current code:

lambda_hook: AwsLambdaHook = AwsLambdaHook(function_name=function_name, region_name=region, log_type="Tail", invocation_type="RequestResponse",config=config, aws_conn_id=connection)
res = lambda_hook.invoke_lambda(payload=json.dumps(payload))

Having the option to trigger lambdas properly is definitely an important feature for this service!

Edited by: anamm on Dec 3, 2020 3:25 AM

Comment: So, what's the question is? See [How do I ask a good question? - Help Center - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thanks. Reworded the question and specified it to a certain service.

Comment: how did you solved this?

Comment: This still seems to be an issue and is not documented in MWAA regarding this limit. The only solution at this time (Jan 2023) seems to be to rewrite the DAG to call the lambda as an async process and update the lambda so that it writes to a location that can be polled by the DAG to determine successful completion.

Comment: This link provides an implementation of the async invoking & waiting operator: https://cevo.com.au/post/revisit-airflow-lambda-operator/

Answer (score 1):

There are some workarounds that can be applied to mitigate this. The first and simplest one I can recommend is to change the invocation of Lambda Function to asynchronous, as Lambda will send a response back to MWAA straight away. With asynchronous invocation the event is handed off to Lambda without having to wait for a response from the function code. This will avoid the timeout errors. For asynchronous invocation change the 'invocation_type' to 'Event' in your dag code.

Another option is to provision your own Load Balancer and send a request to it from the DAG. From here you can configure a listener rule to forward requests to the Lambda function in order to invoke it. Note that you will need to ensure that the load balancer connection idle timeout is set accordingly, otherwise it might drop the connection with the Lambda ENI. Detailed step for this :

1. Create a lambda function with the code you want to run. Change the function timeout configuration to 15 minutes.
2. Create a target group by navigating to EC2--> Target Groups --> Create target group --> Choose target type as Lambda function --> Supply a name --> (no need to enable health check) --> Next --> Select the function name created above from drop down--> Hit create target group
3. Create a loadbalancer by navigating to EC2--> Load balancer --> Create Load Balancer --> Create application load balancer -->  Scheme as internet facing --> Select the VPC same as that of MWAA --> Supply 2 public subnets under Mappings --> Under Listener and routing select protocol as HTTP, Port 80 and choose the target group that is created --> hit create loadbalancer
4. After creating the load balancer select the loadbalancer --> Action --> Edit loadbalancer attributes --> Supply the idle timeout to 900 seconds --> Hit Save the changes
5. Upload the supply the dag script(ensure you have changed the ALB DNS to your ALB DNS which can be located under details tab of your loadbalancer with field "DNS name")
6. Run the dag script in airflow webui and observe further.